# What Are The Shallow Dependencies of spring-webmvc?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to figure out the first level dependencies of spring-webmvc. This is for an environment where I have to manually put in place the dependencies.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/3.0.5.RELEASE
shows a list of 42 dependencies in the "This artifact depends on ..."

When I use the Maven POM in my laptop, I see 7 (all 3.0.5):

1. spring-asm
2. spring-beans
3. spring-context
4. spring-context-support
5. spring-core
6. spring-expression
7. spring-web

Those 42 dependencies are deep dependencies and I think I can count on the 7. The 7 are already to go in the environment so I should just have to go with adding spring-webmvc 3.0.5, right?

Thanks!

Comment: That depends on which features you use. That list of 42 JARs is the worst-case scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=org.springframework.web.servlet&version=3.0.5.RELEASE) to check individual module direct dependencies.